# Multiplication from 2 field, too many variable

Tags: java, android

i practice my beginners skill in android and now i did the application which gets 2 numbers from 2 `editText` and display score in next `editText`

Is it a good practice to do it? I belive better programmers have shortest way to do that.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private EditText editText,editText2,editText3;
    private String a,b,c;
    private Double x1,x2,x3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                a = editText.getText().toString();
                b = editText2.getText().toString();
                x1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
                x2 = Double.parseDouble(b);

                calc(x1,x2);

            }
        });

    }

    private void calc(double x1, double x2){

        x3 = x1 * x2;
        c = String.valueOf(x3);
        editText3.setText(c);


    }
```

Comment: You're always going to have to do this amount of steps since you have to convert from String to double then back to String. This isn't too long of a solution. Good luck learning Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As [MacLean Sochor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7040018/maclean-sochor) commented you cannot reduce the code because those
>   are the exact steps you have to perform.

Anyways, you can use following steps to reduce a code little bit and therefore, make it **readable**.

One suggestion I always follow is to assign listeners in XML layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/multiply" // multiply is '*' in strings.xml
    android:onClick="multiply" /> // Here you are assigning click listener
```

Assigning a suitable name to click listener makes it **readable**. *Provided that, some may argue that the method does not accept the arguments required to perform the task its name suggests.*

```
protected void multiply(View); // View argument is passed instead of two  numbers
```

Advanced techniques to structure the code (reducing as a side effect) include [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html). Watch [Data Binding -- Write Apps Faster (Android Dev Summit 2015)](https://youtu.be/NBbeQMOcnZ0) to get a quick start on [data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

Miscellaneous suggestions:

1. Refactor your variables by giving them meaningful names, for example, x1, x2, and x3 can be renamed to operand, otherOperand, and product. (Note the use of word 'other'. I did not use firstOperand, secondOperand because order does not matter in multiplication.)
2. Avoid using member variables for values you are going to need for function only. For example, apply suggestion 1 to variables a, b, and c and then move them inside `onClick()` and `calc()` method.

Hope this helps.